# How to fix consistent network issues on one computer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, internet, connection

This appears to be a weird problem.

One computer (Windows 10) on my network started showing sluggishness on several websites several weeks ago. Initially, I thought it could be modem/router issue, so I restarted the modem, and Verizon Fios ONT, but the problem remains. I checked other computers on my home network, both wireless and wired, and they are all working without any issues.

Then I suspected that there might be some virus or maleware on this one computer. I did several full scans using Windows Security and McAfee but both did not find any file which was infected.

As a last resort, I did a complete re-install of Windows on it and wiped out all of the installed applications. However, I noticed that it has not fixed the problem. Narrowing down the issues, I see the problem with the following (not a complete list):

- YouTube streaming delays
- DropBox signing in issues
- Dell SupportAssist not installing
- VPN client not installing
- GMail and Google Drive taking exponentially longer to work
- Downloading files in Chrome, FF, Brave, Edge

The above are some of the things I have noticed. Regarding Speed Test, it always shows that it has the maximum speed according to my subscribed plan.

I also changed my network cable (using Cat. 5E) and switched it to a different port on the router. I have also flushed DNS and renewed IPv4 and IPv6.

Nothing appears to have addressed the problem.

---

**Specs:**
Dell OptiPlex 7040
Processor: i7
RAM: 32GB
Windows 10 Pro (build 19044)

**Speed Test**

[image]

Comment: You say on one computer, does that mean that you have access to other computers in this network, and that they are fine? also, what does a speedtest tell you?

Comment: @LPChip Yes, other computers do not show this problem. Speed test shows about 900Mbps download/upload.

Comment: Try uninstalling mcafee (and enabling microsoft defender), and see how much that helps.  Then look at the mtu setting on your network interface and see hoe it compares with other systems.  Also try changing it to 1476 and see if that makes a difference.  What are the specs of the system?

Comment: @davidgo McAfee is no longer there after OS re-installation. MTU is already set to best (1472+28 in my case). Specs added in question.

Comment: Are you running a hard drive or SSD?

Comment: @davidgo 2 SSDs and 1 HDD

Comment: Check the SMART data of the disk, and look for suspicious messages in the Event Viewer.

Comment: @harrymc There are no suspicious messages in Event Viewer. What tool should I use for SMART?

Comment: Try [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy).

Comment: @harrymc Thanks. Speccy showed that all 3 drives are good and there are no errors.

Comment: The remaining possibilities are: Bad network driver, bad router, or the ISP. The last one is the likeliest.

Comment: @harrymc I installed a new ethernet card and the problem did not fix. About bad router and ISP, I'm not sure as none of the above mentioned problems occur on any other computer on my network.

Comment: Is this computer different in any way from the others, for example security software? Try it when booting in Safe Mode with Network (if the network card can work with a generic driver).

Comment: @harrymc The only difference is that this computer is Windows10. Others are Windows11 and MacOS. I've done a complete reinstall of Windows10 on this, after formatting the HDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tried a lot of different things and apparently, the only problem could be a [conflict between IPv4 and IPv6](https://whatismyipaddress.com/ipv6-issues). Unless you have a large number of computers in your home network, you can disable IPv6. On Windows, you can uncheck IPv6 by going to Ethernet properties:

[image: IPv6 Disable]

---

For further reading:

- [How to Fix IPv4/IPv6 ‘No Internet Access’ Error](https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-ipv4-ipv6-no-internet-access-error/)
- [How to resolve a network conflict in an IPv4 network?](https://support.logmeininc.com/central/help/how-to-resolve-a-network-conflict-in-an-ipv4-network)
- [IPv4 vs IPv6: what are they and what's the difference?](https://cybernews.com/what-is-vpn/ipv4-vs-ipv6/)
- [Five ways for IPv6 and IPv4 to peacefully co-exist](https://www.zdnet.com/article/five-ways-for-ipv6-and-ipv4-to-peacefully-co-exist/)